# Symmetric Object Properties of Individuals in Protege

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, object-properties, object-property

I have a small ontology with some individuals (like: `Door1`, `Door2`, `Window1`, `Window2` etc.) belonging to the same class (`Objects`).
I also have an `ObjectProperty:hasLink` which is symmetric. Its domain is `Thing` and range is `Objects` class. 
[image]

Let's say I assign the property to the `Door1` `hasLink` to `Window1` 

[image]

 shouldn't Protege automatically assign the symmetric `ObjectProperty` to the `Window1` pointing to the `Door1` ?

[image]

Comment: Only after you run a reasoner.

Comment: Thank you very much @IvoVelitchkov